# Express Server with Angular2 -- App stuck on "Loading..."

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have done the standard MEAN stack JS application from scratch using Angular-CLI and node/npm. I did ng init and filled out some front end stuff which works fine when I use ng serve, then I created the back end using the code posted below and typing node server in shell. It loads my index.html page which is in src/index and then I try to do a join on src which contains src/app which has my Angular2 code but I get the dreaded Loading... from within my  element. I have watched multiple tutorials and they all did exactly this or similar cookie cutter server code, I cannot figure it out.

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var index = require('./routes/index');
var event = require('./routes/events');

var port = 3000;

var app = express();
    app.set('views',path.join (__dirname, 'src'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/', event);


app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("server listening on port" + port);
});
```

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
//   res.render('../src/index.html');
   res.render('index.html');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: If you are using the angular cli why don't you use the `ng serve`?

Comment: any error on console ?

Comment: Created your 1 GIST for u .. https://gist.github.com/parthghiya/eb337e2ee63ce8785d714e251b7ef0b8
This code works , when u have a dist folder in your angular cli

Comment: No errors in console. ng serve works on my machine for development environment on local-host, but I need an express server to deploy/go into production. I don't think a cloud service like AWS can deploy using ng serve and I need my backend code working with the server and routes.

Answer (score 0):

in Angular CLI app, run `ng build` or `ng build --prod` then node/express serve static directory `dist` not `src`.

Comment: This worked, thank you! But there is still a problem. I changed my static directory to dist and it is now loading but it is not loading properly, specifically the css. Why would ng build break css styles? Also is there no way to get an express server to load an angular-cli app without building it?

Comment: `Why would ng build break css styles?` -> no, ng serve and ng build are same, ng build only output to file, but ng serve run in memory to improve performance. `Also is there no way to get an express server to load an angular-cli app without building it?` -> as first question, you must build angular cli to get real files.

Comment: I'm not sure, but when I run ng build --prod and then run my server.js it is serving up dist folder and the right html and loading the angular content but it is not loading any CSS and some of the images and icons. When I use ng serve it loads eveything correctly. Could this be an error in my static folder loaded by express?  I am using: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use("/", './routes/index');  and then  var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('index.html');
});